# Missing $ inserted Error without using any $

Tags: errors, memoir

Hi I am getting it in the lines:

Missing $ inserted.
 
                $

I never used any $ .

```
[13] Chebrolu, Kameswari, Bhaskaran Raman, and Ramesh R. Rao. "A network layer approach to enable TCP over multiple interfaces." Wireless Networks 11.5 (2005): 637-650.\newline
[15] Barré, Sébastien, Christoph Paasch, and Olivier Bonaventure. "Multipath TCP: from theory to practice." NETWORKING 2011. Springer Berlin Heidelberg, 2011. 444-457.\newline
```

I am getting error in the line beginning with [15] .

Exact Error message:

```
Missing $ inserted.
<inserted text> 
                $
l.40 [15] Barr�
               �, S��bastien, Christoph Paasch, and Olivier Bonaventure. "Mu...
```

Comment: It is always best if you show the exact error message from TeX. Normally this error means you have some character such as `_`  which can only be used in math mode.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I have an acute accent e .

Comment: @DavidCarlisle plz see the edit.

Comment: oh that look like an encoding problem and the é has not been understood. Have you specified `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` ? Really it is very hard to debug if you only show fragments not a complete test case. Also but possibly unrelated to the error, is this your source file? how come you are numbering by hand with `[15]` ??? rather than let latex handle all numbering and cross references.

Comment: Note the added error message shows that é is being interpreted as _two_ characters so almost certainly the input is in UTF-8 encoding (where this is two bytes) but TeX is treating the input as a single byte encoding.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thanks, what should be done to remove, i tried some possible solns ?

Comment: as I said it is very hard to debug if you do not make a full example but I would guess adding `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` to teh preamble would fix it, or you could enter  é  as `\'{e}`  but separately the input should not be `[15]...` but something like `\bibitem{zzz}...`

Answer (score 1):

The e acute has been added as UTF-8 encoding so you need

```
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
```

in the preamble, or you could enter é as `\'{e}` .